# Average image of MNIST

Tags: python, numpy, mnist

Working with the MNIST dataset, I am trying to find the average image for each distinct digit (0-9). The following code gives me each distinct image from the dataset, but I am not sure how I would get the mean for each class (0-9)

```
data = io.loadmat('mnist-original.mat')

x, y = data['data'].T, data['label'].T

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.5)


a=np.unique(y, return_index=True)
b = a[1]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,4.5))
for i in b:
    img=x[i][:].reshape(28,28)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by *trying to find the average image for each distinct digit (0-9)* ?

Comment: i seem to have figured it out, but basically i was looking for the mean for each image, so the dataset has 70,000 handwritten images, i wanted the average image for each digit. Ex: average image for 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the "average" image for zero is the average of all training data with label = 0.
For example:

```
avgImg = np.average(x_train[y_train==0],0)
```

I think this is what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
for i in range(10):
    avgImg = np.average(x_train[y_train==i],0)
    plt.subplot(2, 5, i+1)
    plt.imshow(avgImg.reshape((16,16))) 
    plt.axis('off')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) provides this type of functionality in a vectorized manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
digits, means = npi.group_by(y).mean(x)
```